# Is it guaranteed that C++ compiler won't generate branch if the condition depends on the template type and is known at compile time?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

Suppose I have this function:

```
template<typename Side>
int GetSide(std::pair<int, int> i)
{
    if (Side::mIsLeft)
        return i.first;
    else
        return i.second;
}
```

I see that if `mIsLeft` is `const` (even not `constexpr`) compiler (gcc/clang) won't generate any branch:

```
int GetSide<LeftSide>(std::pair<int, int>):
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  mov QWORD PTR [rbp-16], rdi
  mov eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
  pop rbp
  ret
```

In contrast to when `mIsLeft` was NOT `const`, which a branch would be generated (as expected.)

Now, my question is: Is this behavior (not generating a branch) enforced by standard, or guaranteed in anyway? Or it's just compiler seeing the opportunity and using it? (this is generated even in `-O0`)
What if `mIsLeft` is `constexpr` would that change anything?

You can check the code [here on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/eKRfaw).

Why do I care?
Before finding this, for a situation like this, I'd use `enable_if` and have two different template specialization to avoid the unnecessary branch, but this can simplify lots of code.

Comment: It is guaranteed if `if constexpr` is used. If `mIsLeft` is just `const` then its value is not necessary known at compile time (for example when it is exported from a dll) and therefore branching can not be removed.

Comment: The standard doesn't say how compilers should generate code, just what the result should be. However, `if (false)` is pretty easy to optimize for.

Comment: @VTT would it change if `mIsLeft` is constexpr? no `if constexpr`, we're still on pre-c++17 compiler.

Comment: Is that a purely standard based, theoretical question, or a what happens in practice in 99% of cases question?

Comment: @curiousguy standard based. I can see what's happening.

Comment: @MehrdadMomeny The standard is never specified in term of generated code, only in term of "observable behavior".

Answer (score 3):

No, the standard doesn't specify how compilers should generate code. Compilers are allowed to emit a branch even if the condition is a compile-time constant.

On the other hand, these days, optimizing compilers do their best to remove unnecessary branches, so it can be considered a compiler bug, if a compile-time-constant based `if` doesn't get optimized away.

Answer (score 0):

The details of your specific case are not completely known to us, but in general the answer is no. A const variable can of course be initialized with something that is not known at compile time, e.g. user input.

You should use a constexpr value and an if constexpr check (if possible in your code base).

Comment: Yeah, but the motivation behind that minimal example could be a more complicated use case. Anyway, nothing wrong with your question and "if constexpr" is the way to go if you want guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

Using if constexpr you would discard the branch you don't go in.

Constexpr If

> The statement that begins with if constexpr is known as the constexpr
> if statement.
>
> In a constexpr if statement, the value of condition must be a
> contextually converted constant expression of type bool. If the value
> is true, then statement-false is discarded (if present), otherwise,
> statement-true is discarded.
>
> The return statements in a discarded statement do not participate in
> function return type deduction:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if

More doc here:
https://blog.tartanllama.xyz/if-constexpr/

Example here:

```
struct LeftSide
{
    static constexpr bool mIsLeft=true;
};

struct RightSide
{
    static constexpr bool mIsLeft=false;
};

template<typename Side>
int GetSide(std::pair<int, int> i)
{
    if constexpr (Side::mIsLeft)
        return i.first;
    else
        return i.second;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout<<GetSide<LeftSide>({1,2})<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<GetSide<RightSide>({3,4})<<std::endl;    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

1

4